# Create one histogram for S2 ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, histogram, reducers

I'm trying to compute ONE histogram for an entire ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine (example code here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b10f5136a79a6309e381ae11aa9b7431)
What I'm doing now to achieve the result I want, is to calculate the histograms for each individual image `histogram1` and add them up - such as here in Python API:

```
for j in range(0,norm_size):
  print('Procressing Image #', j+1, ' out of ', norm_size)
  image = ee.Image(norm_list.get(j));
  histogram1 = image.reduceRegion(
      reducer = ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0,1,255),
      geometry = s2_norm.geometry(),
      maxPixels = 10e9
      ).get(band)
  try:
    dic = histogram1.getInfo()
    if j==0:
      for l in range(0,255):
        bins[0,l] = dic[l][0]
        counts[0,l] = dic[l][1] 
    else:
      for l in range(0,255):
        counts[0,l] = counts[0,l] + dic[l][1] 

  except (IndexError):
    print(j,'Empty')
    pass
```

This works fine, but it takes AGES, because of the `getInfo()`.

Is there a smart GEE way, to get one histogram for the entire Imagecollection, that is not an image but a simple list, such as in the example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A histogram is basically a list of paired values. So, you can map it with a function without a for/loop. Following code snippet has essential part of algorithm for producing histogram chart for the entire Imagecollection.

```
var s2_norm_lst = s2_norm.toList(s2_norm.size());

var allValues = s2_norm_lst.map(function (ele) {
  
  var histogram = ee.Image(ele).reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram(0,1,255),
        geometry: s2_norm.geometry(),
        maxPixels: 10e9}
      ).get(band);
  
  return ee.List(ee.Array(histogram).toList());
  
});

allValues = ee.List(allValues).flatten();

var len = allValues.size();

var list = ee.List.sequence(0, len.subtract(1), 2);

var tot_list = list.map(function(ele){

  var start = ee.Number(ele).int(); 
  var end = ee.Number(ele).add(2).int(); 

  var new_list = ee.List([]);
  var element = ee.List(allValues.slice(start, end));

  new_list = new_list.add(element);

  return new_list.get(0);

});

//print(tot_list);

var allValues = tot_list.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.List(ele).get(0);
  
});

var allCounts = tot_list.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.List(ele).get(1);
  
});

var chart3 = ui.Chart.array.values({array: allCounts, axis: 0, xLabels: allValues})
                .setOptions({
                  title: 'Sentinel 2 normalized B2 band Histogram',
                  colors: ['blue'],
                  hAxis: {
                    'title': 'Normalized values',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  vAxis: 
                    {title: 'Count', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
                  
                }).setChartType('ColumnChart');

print(chart3);
```

Complete code can be accessed [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a194ba48ba2b4bd2381e80afad78ac41). After running it in GEE code editor (it only takes a few seconds), I got following result.

[image]

First chart (blue) was obtained with **ui.Chart.image.histogram** for first image in collection (your histo image was not useful for getting histogram for entire collection and it cannot be added to Map Canvas). Only works with a scale higher than 35 meters (however, B2 bands have a scale of 10 meters). Second and third charts (red) are showing for, respectively, first image and entire collection. Both were obtained with **ui.Chart.array.values**.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped. Added something, so that in the end I would get exactly the same kind of list, as I would get from the single image processing: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b4903192bb3438ec0cdbaab2135cc2cd

Comment: You're welcome. I added some lines for producing histogram. Here's the code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/21085722697599cbd4960d53cba14b01 and image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGsav.jpg .